# Will the stackexchange 2.0 sites continue to be updated with new features when Stackoverflow is?

Tags: discussion, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does StackExchange 2.0 Share the Same CodeBase with SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55725/does-stackexchange-2-0-share-the-same-codebase-with-so)

Will the codebase for all the sites launched through area51 stay the same as the codebase for the original trilogy? Will they miss out on future releases? How will they be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the [SE 2.0 announcement blog post.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)

> Currently, the combined Stack Exchange
> and Stack Overflow teams are in the
> process of merging the two code bases
> to take advantage of the best features
> of the two systems. Sites created
> under the Stack Exchange 2.0 model
> will take advantage of the new code
> base, as will Stack Overflow, Server
> Fault, and Super User.