# Does StackExchange use Shapado?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies were used to build the Trilogy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy)

Does StackExchange (including Stack Overflow, SuperUser, Server Fault, etc.) use Shapado? Else, what software does it use?

Comment: Check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Answer (score 4):

StackExchange sites use StackExchange (by Fog Creek, written in ASP.NET). Shapado is just a clone.

Comment: Not sure how accurate that is nowadays? See also [Does StackExchange 2.0 Share the Same CodeBase with SO?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55725/does-stackexchange-2-0-share-the-same-codebase-with-so) (But, better answered at that question, or at [Which tools and technologies were used to build the Trilogy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy))

Comment: WOW. StackExchange was written in ASP.NET??? Gross and surprising.