# How did a question get posted on meta without a [bug], [feature-request], [discussion], or [support] tag?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, required-tags

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63280/does-stackexchange-use-shapado) only has a "qa" tag:

[image]

Comment: Questions migrated to a Meta site now automatically get the [discussion] tag (unless they already have one of the others, which is rare but [not unheard of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340503/4751173)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to scroll down just a little further:

### migrated from stackoverflow.com

Migrated posts don't have to have the required tags for obvious reasons.

Comment: Well that seems... obvious, now that you point it out.  I'd like to say that I'd assumed that the migrator had to tag it with a required meta tag, but the truth is that I hadn't even thought about it.